# Как группировать элементы в Windows Forms?

Tags: winforms

```
 private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox5.Visible = true;
        pictureBox6.Visible = true;
        pictureBox7.Visible = true;
        pictureBox8.Visible = true;
        pictureBox9.Visible = true;
        pictureBox1.Visible = true;
        pictureBox3.Visible = true;
        pictureBox4.Visible = true;
        pictureBox2.Visible = true;
    }
```

Например у меня много картинок и лейблов которые надо включать-выключать поочереди, Как это правильно делать?

Answer (score 0):

```
pictureBox2.Enabled = false;
```

Попробуй так